# Using first person as a polite way to ask second person to do something

Tags: modal-verbs, politeness, will-would

I emailed someone asking for a piece of information. He wrote back:
"I'd contact X for the latest data."

I'm having trouble understanding what he (a native speaker) meant by using the word *would*. It seems he meant number 2 below, as a polite way to suggest I do something.

1. I'll contact X and get the latest data (I'll then send it to you).
2. If I were you, I'd contact X. In other words, you should contact X instead of me.

Can we rule out one of the two or is it ambiguous to a native ear as well?

Comment: Your instincts are correct. As a native speaker, it doesn't sound ambiguous. It also makes sense for him not to be a middle man for your data reques!

Comment: Yes, you could remove the polite starter *I'd* to give you "Contact X for the latest data." Note that in your #1 version, you replaced would with will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2 is the only way I would interpret that response.

The author is telling you what he would do in that circumstance.  It's a way of giving advice without taking responsibility for that advice.